# Create a data frame with YouTube video details using the tuber package

Tags: r, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the tuber R package to get data for a set of specific videos. I'm able to get video details for individual videos but want to do that for an entire dataset by video ID. Here's a selection of videos I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

myvideos <- tibble(
  timestamp = c("2018-03-23 07:11:25",
                "2018-03-22 07:35:27",
                "2018-03-21 07:22:27",
                "2018-03-20 07:26:33",
                "2018-03-16 10:21:35"),
  video_id = c("nd_EYo96lmo",
               "LCnbyCp74vg",
               "SRkXjtMqN0o",
               "XfyEpmQM7bw",
               "5r6A2NexF88")
)
```

When I try to simply apply the get_video_details function to the video_id column, I get an error, even though the package manual says it works with a list:

```
library(tuber)

vid_details <- get_video_details(video_id = myvideos$video_id, part = 
"snippet")

Error in vapply(elements, encode, character(1)) : 
 values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 5
```

I get the same error when adding the video ids as a comma separated list in the function above. I tried the following and got closer to what I want, but the data I need (title and channel title) are embedded in a list:

```
videos <- sapply(myvideos$video_id, function(video_id) {
  videos <- data.frame(get_video_details(video_id = video_id, part = 
  "snippet"))
})
```

Anyone know how to have tuber run through the list of ids in a data frame and append the details obtained from the function onto the data frame? Either a tweak to my code or all new code to do what I need?